# Sum dynamic ranges based on numbers in a helper column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with a list of numbers I want to sum.

There are varying ranges after I have imported the data and am struggling to find the ranges and insert the totals(sum) of each category.

There is a Helper column in column "A" which has the number 4 where the category starts and the number 7 where it ends.

I want to sum the numbers in column "I" for rows between 4 (where 4 appears in column "A") and 7 (where 7 appears in column "A") and place the total in column "I" in the row that 7 appears in column "A".

Here is the code I have so far.

```
    Sub Sumtask()
Dim s As Long, p1 As Range, p2 As Range, p4 As Range, p7 As Range

For s = 10 To 500
     Set p1 = Range("A" & s)
     Set p2 = Range("I" & s)
     Set p4 = Range("I" & s)
     Set p7 = Range("I" & s)
     If p1.Value = 4 Then p4 = Range("I" & s)
     If p1.Value = 7 Then p7 = Range("I" & s)
     p2.Offset(9, -1).Value = Application.Sum(Range(p4.Offset(, -1), p7.Offset(, -1)))
Next s
End Sub
```

I also have

[image: image of worksheet]

Any help would be helpful as I have been searching for the right syntax for some time.

Comment: What's the difference between the two images?? Both are too much to look at and at the same time don't show which column you want to sum.

Comment: The image was doubled up, sorry. The column that I was trying to sum has the heading 'Quantity', there are some hidden columns which makes this column "I" on the work sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the answer with some others help.
Would like to share it here for anyone else who looks up a similar question.

```
Sub Sumtask()
           Dim Rf As Range, Rg As Range, A$
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1)
           Set Rf = .Find(4, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not Rf Is Nothing Then
                   A = Rf.Address
                   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Do
                   Set Rg = .Find(7, Rf):  If Rg.Row < Rf.Row Then Exit Do
                    If Rg.Row > Rf.Row + 1 Then Rg(1, 9).Value2 = Application.Sum(Range(Rf(2, 9), Rg(0, 9)))
                   Set Rf = .Find(4, Rg)
            Loop Until Rf.Address = A
                   Set Rf = Nothing:   Set Rg = Nothing
                   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This seems a better way by using the Address syntax